# gvfs-mount auto password

Tags: security, password, ftp, sftp, gvfs

I would like to make shortcuts for gvfs mounts (I prefer to mount from the shell). For this, it is quite necessary/convenient not to have to enter the password for the `ftp://` and `sftp://` connections . Currently the only way I know is:

```
echo 12345 | gvfs-mount sftp://user@example.com/
```

Even though I can make the file's rights `700` (or even `100`), I'm not sure if it's reasonably safe. Is it worse than `.netrc` items? I know about `ssh-copy-id`, but I can't access shell on most of my `sftp` servers.

Is there a better (standard) alternative to my approach? What do `nautilus`/`caja` do when they store the passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `expect` to provide the credentials each time you want to connect. It's not super secure but gives you what you want.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect --
set timeout -1
spawn gvfs-mount {args}
expect "User"
send "joe\n"
expect "Password:"
send "xxxxx\n"
expect eof
```

**Source:** *[gvfs-mount specify username password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005876/gvfs-mount-specify-username-password)*

Comment: Thanks, looks better than sending the password no matter if it's asked for. And thanks for the `spawn`, `expect`, `send` combination. I'll look into that tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just like you, I like to mount/umount my filesystems from the command line.

### About the stdin option

> I'm not sure if it's reasonably safe. Is it worse than .netrc items?

You should be aware that on many systems, process names and command line arguments are visible to all users.  In Linux for example, do `grep -a . /proc/*/cmdline` to see them all.

That said, in some shells including bash, `echo` is a built-in command so there's no process launched.

So, as far as I know, it should be no worse than `.netrc`.  Double check your file permissions in any case.

### SFTP

You can have `gvfs-mount sftp://somehost/somepath` work without a password. (I just tested this successfully.)

The recommended solution is to use key-based authentication, not store any password anywhere.

For example, see [authentication - How can I set up password-less SSH login? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login/46935#46935) and [Easiest way to copy ssh keys to another machine? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine/4833#4833) (it's written for Ubuntu but works the same for other Unices).

> I know about ssh-copy-id, but I can't access shell on most of my sftp servers.

ssh-copy-id is just a handy shortcut. You don't need shell access to set key-based authentication, but you do need access to your home dir.

If you can access you files interactively with SFTP, you can most probably set up `~/.ssh/` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, unless the administrator carefully prevented this, but that would be shooting in their feet.  Actually the admin should *encourage* users to set up key based authentication.  Check what's the policy with them.

If you just need to set up only one key you just have to copy your *public* (not private) key file generated above (possibly `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to a remote file in directory `.ssh` named `authorized_keys` and set permission `600` (read-write for you, nothing for others).

### FTP

Regarding ftp urls, the traditional answer is to use a `~/.netrc` as explained e.g. on https://askubuntu.com/a/359802/68124 .

Alas, it works very well with a zillion ftp clients, old and new, including `curlftpfs`, but (on Ubuntu 14.04 at least) `gvfsmount` ignores it.

Perhaps `curlftpfs` would suit your use case.  The main difference is that you choose your mount point instead of having `gvfs-mount` compute one.

```
curlftpfs ftp://host/ ~/mymountpoint
```

### SFTP, again

If you like the `curlftpfs` option, you may consider for your sftp urls,

```
sshfs host:/some/remote/path ~/myothermountpoint
```

And if wonder whether sshfs needs shell access, Wikipedia says: [The client interacts with the remote file system via the SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP),[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS)

A final word: for tools that need an explicit mount point, think to create an empty dir first at the correct path.  And if you're trying several times or change options, remember to `fusermount -u somepath` to umount before trying to mount again.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The problem of accessing shell has a lot to do with my restricted access to the system, I can basically access only webpage root, and I can't add arbitrary files even there.

Comment: Hum, thanks for the feedback.  The situation is a little silly.  If this happened to me, I would write them a request (as a bug or suggestion for improvement) to enable key-based authentication and be open for alternative providers.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, but the idea that you can suggest such things to any sysadmin you have to deal with is a bit crazy...

Comment: I don't know your setup, if it is your university, your work, a public service provider, whatever.  I can't guess its sanity.  Anyway back to your first question, if you have no choice don't worry too much about the "echo mypassword | gvfs-mount".